# Field name from inside a FormType in Symfony2 Forms?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

Please look at the example:

```
/** @var FormBuilderInterface $builder */

$builder->add('foo', new MyFormType());
$builder->add('bar', new MyFormType());
$builder->add('baz', new MyFormType());
```

I need to get current's field name from inside a `MyFormType` instance (by the field name i mean: `foo`, `bar` and `baz` from the example above). How can i do this? What method to choose and how can i obtain field's name inside it?

More generally, i need to call some external function with field name as an argument for every form element with specific type, so i decided to do it from inside a `FormType` class, it looks like good encapsulation.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the field name asfar as i know, you can get the parent though.
From inside the MyFormType buildForm method:

```
$parent = $builder->getParent();
```

If i understand your question correct i think the best way to do it is to add a constructor in your MyFormType that accepts a string:

```
$builder->add('foo', new MyFormType('foo'));
```

Comment: Thanks, for your reply. I though about this idea, but i don't want to duplicate field name just yet. DRY is kinda my credo )

Comment: If you find another appoach tell me.